# prevent concurrent loops running

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function simply like below

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE proc=0";
$r = mysql_query($q);
if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        mysql_query('UPDATE SET proc=0 FROM tbl1 id=' . $row['id']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl2(value,tbl_id) VALUE (1,$row['id'])");
    }
}
```

Now in concurrent sessions, I will face a problem.
"two rows will be inserted for tbl2 but i want to have one!"

for technically reason I can not use limit or WHERE for SELECT.

Now I want to know how can I prevent this problem with my condition.

**Edit:**
My question is "SELECT * FROM tbl1 where proc=0"; in two concurrent sessions will return same thing,for example 10 rows will return for each session. But I want to prevent running loop for two sessions at the same time! 
I use create file and check if exits
or update a field in database and checked if allowed to continue or not. But none of them could prevent running on same session.

**UPDATE2:** This is just an example to show my idea, and functions are not what i used but generally this shows my problem and script flowdata schema.

Answer (score 0):

Well , then add a **`break`** and come out of the **`while`** loop.. Do like this here

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
mysql_query('UPDATE SET proc=0 FROM tbl1 id='.$row['id']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl2(value,tbl_id) VALUE (1,$row['id'])");
break; //<--- Add here
}
```

<sup>Disclaimer : You are using an obselete database API i.e. the `mysql_*` functions which is deprecated. Switch to `MySQLi` or `PDO`.</sup>

Comment: with break program will jump out of loop and my problem is two sessions are in loop and I have no idea how can i manage them to insert only one value into tbl2. and i use mysql_query for example to show my schema in my mind!

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are looking for is [Semaphores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php)

Basically logic is that you acquire the lock before executing any code, and release the lock after the code is completed, so that other sessions can acquire the semaphore.